# Getting GPS data in background mode on iOS with Qt app

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, qt, gps

Location updates stops being delivered to application in background after about a 20 minutes. Application is not closed because when I click on app icon it is brought back from background in state I left it and then updates starts comming again. I can also see that in top right corner of task bar there is little arrow when it is displayed I got the updates, when it disappears I'm not receiving updates. I'm getting GPS data every 5 seconds, keep it in some queue and every minute I connect to my server via tcp socket and send these updates. When top right arrow disappears my app no longer connects to the server (and it should even with empty data) so I assume that app is in some suspend mode.

I have written app in Qt/QML and then converted the project to XCode. I have checked "Background Modes" (Location updates, Background fetch) in Capabilities. I have in plist file UIBackgroundModes fetch,location. I have also NSLocationWhenInUse NSLocationAlways and NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUse UsageDescription And App in system checking has 
settings->myapp->location->Always

Maybe the problem is that app is suspended or put to sleep. In some other project I have used some code to prevent screen fading with some simple code:

```
void IosLockHelper::setTimerDisabled() {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
}
```

Is this this case? But I don't want to have screen turned on all time.

It should continue sending gps location to my server in some intervals it can be 1,5 minutes.
I'm testing on iOS 12.3.1 and with Qt 5.12.3

Thanks in advance
Marek

Comment: adding setIdleTimerDisabled doesn't solve the issue. Anyone has any idea ?